# chkrootkit issues

Tags: chkrootkit

When I use `chkrootkit -q`, I get:

```
/lib/modules/5.3.0-1035-aws/vdso/.build-id /lib/modules/5.4.0-1025-aws/vdso/.build-id /lib/modules/4.15.0-1044-aws/vdso/.build-id
/lib/modules/5.3.0-1035-aws/vdso/.build-id /lib/modules/5.4.0-1025-aws/vdso/.build-id /lib/modules/4.15.0-1044-aws/vdso/.build-id
not tested

ens5: PACKET SNIFFER(/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd[714])
not tested
```

Please, anyone knows what means these issues? and if they are false positives or not?

Answer (score 0):

`chkrootkit` is warning you about these filenames because they're "hidden" (they begin with a "`.`"), and `ls` won't list them without `-a` or `-A`.

You can see if they're part of a package with `dpkg -S`, and further investigate the files with `ls`, `file`, `od`, `less`, `readelf`.